How do I hot switch images in my AWS Task Definition now that there is 'ECS software version consistency'?
Background: I run a large number of ECS Fargate services via Cloudformation. There are 3 Cloudformation stacks for our different environments (Dev, Staging, Prod). In prod and staging, we follow the expected CI/CD pipeline that is consistent with AWS's new software version consistency changes on July 11th.
The issue is our dev environment. We have rapid development cycles and might redeploy a modified version of a tagged image several times in an hour. Previously ECS would respect image tags and every time the container was restarted re-evauluate the ECR tag. This meant we simply uploaded an image and tagged as 'latest' or 'dev' (instead of versioned), and restarted the container to check our changes. Not it seems we are forced to create a new task defintion and update the service every time the image needs to change. This is very time consuming for our development cycles.  Is there a way to set ECS behavior to how it was before 'software version consistency'?

There's an option to force a redeploy of the service without updating the task definition. It's a checkbox in the Console, and an option (which I can't remember) for the CLI. No idea if there's something that would force CloudFormation to do a redeploy.

And yeah, it's an absolute PITA, but it's also how Lambda has worked for a long time.

@kdgregory I deleted my former reply so I could correct it. Using the 'force new deployment' on the service does seem to make ECS re-evaluate the ECR image tag! It's not perfect, but it's better than what I've been grappling with. Thank you!

This is why it is always better to use distinct image IDs or immutable tags instead of reusing something like latest or dev. If you were deploying to EC2 instead of Fargate you would have run into caching issues and inconsistent deployments already.
